# Get multiple values from jquery and post it to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?= $servicii_content[$j]['title'] ?>" name="check_list" id="check" />
```

i get multiple values from the table above if the checkboxes are checked with jQuery, like this.

```
var temp = $("input:checkbox[name=check_list]:checked").map(function(){  
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
alert(temp);
```

I get the alert with the correct checked values!

I post them later here:

```
url: "/servicii_email.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                families: temp,
```

How can I get the elements of "families" eg.:Family1, Family2, Family3, etc. - which are checked to post it to the php file?  What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can just make string with name of variable and it value. That will be something like this `Family1=true,Family2=false`

On server you just need to split string by `,` and after that split by `=`, you will get two dimensional array `{{Family1, true}, {Family2, false}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `serializeArray()` method:

```
var temp = $("input:checkbox[name=check_list]:checked").serializeArray();
// outputs:  
// [{name:"check_list", value:"theValue"},......n]
```